# Add note to phone number without using contacts in iOS

Tags: iphone, contacts, notes.app

Can the iPhone accomplish what I'm describing below?

On my Android when I view recent calls I can:

- Tap phone number
- Tap i
- Tap add note
- Type a note such as "May order 1000 widgets".

Now the next time the caller phones I will see in the caller display:

555-555-5555.
May order 1000 widgets

I find this very useful. I can decide to answer or let it go to voicemail.

Is this possible in iOS?

Answer (score 1):

Contacts is the system that stores this information on iOS. So, you must create a contact card to add information to a phone number.

I assume you know this already, but if you or anyone else is wondering:

- You can create a contact card from the recents list for any number that doesn't have one
- You can assign a name, nickname, and write notes on a contact card